# Some failed iterations with multiple treatment periods?

Tags: r, stata

I am using the csdid command in stata for panel dataset with multiple treatment periods.

When the command is running some of the iterations fail, but I still get an output. I looked in the helpfile for csdid and it states "Each succesful iteration is represented by a ".", whereas an "x" indicates for some ATT(G,T), the estimation failed."

Can I still use the output results or should I consider another estimator?

Comment: Please remove the *R* tag as your question refers exclusively to Stata language. It also seems your question is more about statistics than the implementation in a given language (Stata or other), so you might want to move it to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ .